# renaming a .local domain to .com for every relayed message

Tags: postfix

Situation: about 10 virtual machines (linux) that run postfix to send e-mails for several users.
Those e-mails are all relayed through a central server which then sends them to the internet.

The virtual machines have names like: redmine.vanheusden.local or scm.vanheusden.local and so on.

I would like the central postfix server to rename *@vanheusden.local to @vanheusden.com for all e-mails it relays before it puts them onto the internet.

I thought I could use masquerade_domains but apparently this (no longer) works?

```
masquerade_domains = vanheusden.com
local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, envelope_recipient, header_sender, header_recipient
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible to use masquerade_domains for this use case.

With masquerade_domains it's possible to strip the domain names of your e-mail addresses.

Example:

```
 /etc/postfix/main.cf:

   masquerade_domains = foo.example.com example.com

strips "any.thing.foo.example.com" to "foo.example.com", but strips "any.thing.else.example.com" to "example.com".
```

Source: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#masquerade

Instead you should use generic mapping. This will allow you to completely rewrite an address however you want.

Example:

```
  /etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

  /etc/postfix/generic:
      @vanheusden.local                  @vanheusden.com
```

Source: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic

Comment: Hi, Your suggestion indeed works fine for @ bla.tld to @ bla.othertld, but not for @ host1.vanheusden.local @ host2.vanheusden.local - for that I would need to enter for each host a mapping. I'm hoping there's a way that any host going through my relay-host is remapped to vanheusden.com. *.vanheusden.local, *.*.vanheusden.local, etc

Comment: I've not needed to do this, but there's a reference in the `generic` man page to using regular expressions in the table - look for `REGULAR EXPRESSION TABLES`